# Do I need a period at the end of a sentence that ends on "pm"?

Tags: punctuation

Do I need a period at the end of a sentence that ends on "pm"?

For example:

> I went to bed last night at 11:00 pm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A sentence must start with a capital letter, and end with a period, question mark, or exclamation mark.

If you follow the mainly British style of omitting periods from am and pm, then the sentence will look like this:

> I went to bed last night at 11:00 pm.

[Period/full stop (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/period-full-stop)

If you follow the mainly American style of using periods in a.m. and p.m., then the sentence will look like this, because the final period also serves to end the sentence:

> I went to bed last night at 11:00 p.m.

[Punctuation (Chicago)](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0040.html)

Comment: Note that there are numerous style guides on the use of AM - A.M.- a.m.- and - am) All the guides that I have come across recommend the use of stops after both letters in the lower case, as in **p.m.** - although this advice appears to be widely ignored.

Comment: @Ronald Sole - that seems a mainly US thing: The (UK) [Guardian style guide](https://www.theguardian.com/info/series/guardian-and-observer-style-guide): times - 1am, 6.30pm, etc; 10 o’clock last night but 10pm yesterday; half past two, a quarter to three, 10 to 11, etc; 2hr 5min 6sec, etc; for 24-hour clock, 00.47, 23.59; noon, midnight (not 12 noon, 12 midnight or 12am, 12pm).

Comment: On the conservative side of UK politics, the Daily Telegraph guide is worth a read - it is more idiosyncratic, there is a list of banned words - random sample: hike (when we mean a rise), huge, iconic, jaw-dropping, loaned (no such verb: used lent), luxury (as an adjective: very tabloid). Americanisms: "Do not use an Americanism when there is a reasonable word of our own: i.e. candidates "stand" for office, they do not "run". But "running mate" is permitted in American election stories. American courts do not contain witness boxes, so witness stand is acceptable in reports of American trials."

Comment: [Daily Telegraph Style Book](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/style-book/) I see that [The Spectator](http://spectatorwriters.blogspot.com/) bans the Oxford comma but enforces "a.m." and "p.m.".

Comment: As a BBC recruit several decades ago my first job was to familiarise myself with the newsroom style guide. It wasn't quite as extreme but references to hoovers, tarmacs and similar were banned. And weapons for arms please (lest alms be misunderstood).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put a full stop if you are ending with p.m.
It is encouraged not to put p.m. at the end of a sentence.
However, for 'pm', you do need to.